# Is it possible to use mutual TLS with deepstream.io?

Tags: deepstream.io

I'd be interested in using mutual TLS between deepstream.io server and deepstream.io-client-js clients. I know deepstream.io's tutorials mention leaving SSL termination to a load balancer like Nginx or HAproxy, but how do I use deepstream.io client to give the appropriate client certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found that you can construct the client with options and one of the options is called *nodeSocketOptions*. This object is used when constructing the underlying websocket, so here you can give it the cert, ca and key, thus enabling mutual tls from client side.

```
const deepstream = require('deepstream.io-client-js'); 
const client = deepstream('localhost:6020', options).login();
```